# Фиксированная высота таблиц

Tags: html, css, responsive, height

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы при изменении размера главного окна, все три таблицы оставались одного и того же размера (из-за того, что слова переносятся в зависимости от ширины, таблицы меняют свой размер).

```html
<link href="http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/2.6/w3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="w3-row-padding w3-padding-24">
  <div class="w3-third w3-hover-shadow w3-light-grey w3-bordered">
    <table class="w3-table w3-bordered w3-striped">
      <tr>
        <th class="w3-center w3-padding-24">
          <h5>Первая консультация</h5>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="w3-center w3-padding-24">Jill</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="w3-center w3-padding-24">Eve</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="w3-center w3-padding-24">Adam</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="w3-center w3-padding-24">
          <button class="w3-btn w3-teal w3-padding-large">Подробнее</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-third w3-hover-shadow w3-light-grey w3-bordered">
    <table class="w3-table w3-bordered w3-striped">
      <tr>
        <th class="w3-center w3-padding-24">
          <h5>Консультирование с элементами психотерапии</h5>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="w3-center w3-padding-24">Jill</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="w3-center w3-padding-24">Eve</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="w3-center w3-padding-24">Adam</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="w3-center w3-padding-24">
          <button class="w3-btn w3-teal w3-padding-large">Подробнее</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-third w3-hover-shadow w3-light-grey w3-bordered">
    <table class="w3-table w3-bordered w3-striped">
      <tr>
        <th class="w3-center w3-padding-24">
          <h5>Индивидуальная психотерапия</h5>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="w3-center w3-padding-24">Jill</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="w3-center w3-padding-24">Eve</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="w3-center w3-padding-24">Adam</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="w3-center w3-padding-24">
          <button class="w3-btn w3-teal w3-padding-large">Подробнее</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Самое простое решение задать фиксированную высоту заголовка таблицы на определенной ширине окна:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    table > tr > th {
        min-height: 300px;
    }
}
```

Ширину окна и высоту заголовка подберите конкретно для вашего случая